# how to send file contents taken using javascript and receive using php and create the file using the received content?

Tags: javascript, php

How do I post file contents from a JQuery `$.post` to a PHP backend.
The received data is saved to a file on the server side.

#### html file

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      $.post('sa.jpg', function(data) {
          passVal(data);
      });

      function passVal(data) {        
          $.post("test.php", {
              str: data
          },
          function(data, status) {
              alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
          });
  }
  </script>
  ...
```

#### php file

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen('11.jpg', "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $data=$_POST['str'];

    fwrite($myfile,$data );
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

i am getting a different value in php side....

Comment: It is unclear what `data` is on the client side. If it is structured content, not a simple string, then you need to either hand it over as array or as serialized string to the ajax call. Likewise on the server side you may need to unserialize the received content. Currently you try to take element `0` of a _string_, which does not make sense.

Comment: You for one should NEVER document.write after load or in a callback. Use innerHTML of some element

Comment: Actualy i want to send a local file to server wwithout using file input..so first took contents of file using javascript,and post to php using ajax..but i am getting a different output in php side..i used document.write,just to print the content...

Comment: formatting, tried to state the question more succinctly, not sure what "different value" means?